# Pick child of type

Tags: typescript

This is my type:

```
type newType = { 
  a: string, 
  b: string,
  c: { 
    x: string,
    y: string,
    z: string,
  },
}
```

How can I pick `c.y` only? I want my output to be:

```
type newTypePick = { 
  c: { 
    y: string,
  },
}
```

I don't want to write manual code like:

```
type newTypePick = {
  c: Pick<newType['c'], 'y'>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of [ts-essentials](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials) and we have a utility type called [DeepPick](https://github.com/ts-essentials/ts-essentials/tree/master/lib/deep-pick) which can be helpful in your scenario.

I *stress* here that it will be beneficial for you to have this approach only when you need more generic approach (you need to do it at least twice in different places, number of levels may differ), otherwise please ignore this and use approach with `Pick` and mapped type

- If use `ts-essentials` utility type in TypeScript Playground - https://tsplay.dev/NdyA6m
- The full extracted utility type in TypeScript playground (with same example at the very end) - https://tsplay.dev/mZy49N
- The simplified extracted utility type (without autocomplete and less edge cases) in TypeScript playground - https://tsplay.dev/N7Q14W

You can use this type to get only values that you need:

```js
type newType = { 
  a: string, 
  b: string,
  c: { 
    x: string,
    y: string,
    z: string,
  },
}

type OnlyCY = DeepPick<
  // ^? { c: { y: string } }
  newType,
  {
    c: {
      y: never
    }
  }
>;
```

The simplified solution will look this short and nice:

```js
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol | undefined | null;

type Builtin = Primitive | Function | Date | Error | RegExp;

type AnyRecord = Record<string, any>;

export type DeepPick<Type, Filter> = Type extends Builtin
  ? Type
  : Filter extends AnyRecord
  ? {
      // iterate over keys of Type, which keeps the information about keys: optional, required or readonly
      [Key in keyof Type as Key extends keyof Filter ? Key : never]: Filter[Key & keyof Filter] extends true
        ? Type[Key]
        : Key extends keyof Filter
        ? DeepPick<Type[Key], Filter[Key]>
        : never;
    }
  : never;
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) in a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like so:

```
type NewType = { 
  a: string, 
  b: string,
  c: { 
    x: string,
    y: string,
    z: string,
  },
}

type NewTypePick = {
  [K in keyof Pick<NewType, "c">]: Pick<NewType["c"], "y">
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDuAVc0C8UDeUBQUoEMAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaHPAI2LKrvtygGNitueAB5sKNBoKghRHCXjwAvGeK54AvlzXZsoSLATJIABUo8A1lHQZuAbQDSUGlDMQQAewBmUE%20YA8cJBRGACIeYIA%20AF1iHzN-AxQbUODIkJAI7DUAbiA)

---

P. S. Type names should start with a capital by convention.

Answer (score 0):

for this resone use this code:

```
type PickY<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends 'c' ? Pick<T[K], 'y'> : T[K];
};

type newType = { 
  a: string, 
  b: string, 
  c: { 
    x: string,
    y: string,
    z: string,
  },
};

type newTypePick = PickY<newType>;
```

and if you use newTypePick, you'll get the desired output:

```
type newTypePick = { 
  a: string, 
  b: string, 
  c: { 
    y: string,
  },
};
```

Comment: thank you, but i dont want `a` and `b`. i want only `c`